# Unable to create directory while adding pictures

Tags: wordpress

I have the following issue in WordPress whenever I upload pictures. I have already added the following
code to wp-config.php

define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );

but still, I get this issue

"Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2021/03. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be permission issue. Try to give recurring writable permission on wp-content folder.

Comment: Hi @MominIqbal Can you please check out the screenshot links that are attached now on the main question. I have attached screenshots for the wp-content and upload folders. Can you please check whether the settings are right?

Comment: You need to mark `Recurse into subdirectories` when you are changing the permission of wp-content folder.

Comment: Hi, @SeniorWordPressDeveloper  I still run into the same error even after running the recurse into subdirectories for such a long time....do you have some other ideas or solutions to solve this?

Comment: Do you use Terminal? If yes, then try to change the recursive permission of wp-content folder using command line. Try to give `777` instead of `755` or try to change permission using cpanel..

Comment: Hi @SeniorWordPressDeveloper it worked with 777 Recurse into subdirectories config, thank you. I appreciate your quick response